# flatten JSON value stored as varchar in snowflake to columns

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

one of our tables in snowflake contains the below kind of json value stored as a varchar

- [image]

How do I get to this?

- [image]

in this example I have achieved this by using SPLIT_PART

Not all values have two keys inside the json:

- [image]

in the above case I want it to look like this:

- [image]

And effectively, how to I ensure that I capture the case that more keys and values come into the json?.. 2 more columns?... how can I write a query that can automatically count for all the cases??, or is that not recommended?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON as text?

Comment: Are you really looking for that specific column structure, or would you rather have columns of something like `AE_alarm_state` and `AE_total_reboot_counter`, and have the values of those come through the individual rows? What you have above is likely doable, but awfully convoluted and would be very difficult to query effectively.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild... I'm happy to shift to your option number one.. I'm still in the design phase, so that alternative is definitely useful.. thank you